# Open App from android browser if it exists on device

Tags: android

scenario:
i get an sms with link like this https://www.xyz.com. once i click on the link it opens a browser and if the app exists on my device [given it has the above link in its data scheme] like below

```
</intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https"  android:host="www.xyx.com" />        
  </intent-filter>
```

when ever the browser opens the https://www.xyz.com the app is opened.

problem:
this works perfect in  emulator. i believe it does in nexus devices too.

but, i tried on htc one x and samsung s3 ... it didnt work.
even the app is present the browser opens the webpage.

is it something the manufacturer done to the OS. theoretically it works in emulators. 
now i am worried to publish the app since. most of the devices out there are samsung's htc's etc..,

should i use mime return from that page type now?

is there something i am missing?